# Jquery clone html element to texteara

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

```
<ins id="widget"
     style=""
     data-lang="fr"
     data-city-id="669"
     data-font-color="000000"
     data-background-color="ffffff"
     data-border-color="c0c0c0"
     data-datetime-color="000000"
     data-input-background="ffffff"
     data-next-background="d8d8d8">
</ins>
<textarea id="the-code"></textarea>
<button type="button" id="get-code">Get the code</button>
```

Im trying to clone the ins element to the textarea with Jquery

```
$("#get-code").on("click", function () {
    var clone = $("#widget").clone();
    $("#the-code").val(clone);
});
```

The cloned content return `[object Object]` in the textarea and not the html code `< ins >`

Example : [**`FIDDLE`**](http://jsfiddle.net/ftmdmbc2/)

Comment: @GhostCat OK it's noted!

Comment: Thank you very much for the kind and quick comeback!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need to clone the element just get the **[`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML)** property of dom object.

```js
$("#get-code").on("click", function() {
  $("#the-code").val($("#widget")[0].outerHTML);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ins id="widget" style="" data-lang="fr" data-city-id="669" data-font-color="000000" data-background-color="ffffff" data-border-color="c0c0c0" data-datetime-color="000000" data-input-background="ffffff" data-next-background="d8d8d8">
    </ins>
<textarea id="the-code"></textarea>
<button type="button" id="get-code">Get the code</button>
```